# Write on texture memory/ access image neighbourhood

Tags: cuda

Is there any way to write on texture memory?
I need to access(read and write) the neighbourhood of a pixel in an image. What will be the effective way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

devices of **compute capability 2.x** have support for **surface memory**. Take a look at Section 3.2.4.2 Surface Memory and Section 3.2.4.4 **Read/Write Coherency** in Cuda C Programming Guide 3.2 or above.

Other way is load data into the share memory space within a block with an extra padding of 1 pixel. However, performance depends on the computation of the kernel. If there are really few operations, load the share memory will not compensate.

Hope this help.

Comment: Could you please answer the following question as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349198/cuda-surface-memory-error