# cuda surface memory error

Tags: cuda

My cuda code works fine. but when I include the following on top of my code it gives some errors.

```
surface<void,2> sImg;

fatal   : Parsing error near '.surf': syntax error
```

How can I solve this?

When I declare "sImg" inside the main method it compiles..

---

The following doesnt work..

```
surface<void,2> sImg;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it looks like an error due to code *before* the surface declaration, in the code you are not showing

Comment: I'm agree with @lurscher. Could you show a bit more about the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed 
 Properties-->CUDA Runtime API-->GPU-->GPR Architecture1 to sm_20
Now it compiles..

Answer (score 0):

Are you declaring it inside a .cu file where the kernel using the surface is declared ?

That statements needs to be parsed by the nvcc compiler to become effective.

If that does not work then post the error log of the compiler.